# Binary text classification: why can LSTM fail to fit, while Dense net fits normally?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, kaggle

I have a dataset of texts with two columns that contain textual data and binary target variable. The classes are balanced. Using Keras, first I constructed a two-input Dense net:

```
# Constructing a MLP with two inputs (one for each sentence in pair) and shared output part
# First head
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[0], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input1)
flat1 = layers.Flatten()(emb1)
dense11 = layers.Dense(128)(flat1)
dropout11 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense11)
dense12 = layers.Dense(128)(dropout11)
dropout12 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense12)
dense13 = layers.Dense(128)(dropout12)

# Second head
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[1], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input2)
flat2 = layers.Flatten()(emb2)
dense21 = layers.Dense(128)(flat2)
dropout21 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense21)
dense22 = layers.Dense(128)(dropout21)
dropout22 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense22)
dense23 = layers.Dense(128)(dropout22)

# Shared output layers
merged = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([dense13, dense23])
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model_mlp = models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

```
model_mlp.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[Precision(), Recall(), f1, AUC()])

model_mlp.fit([train_inputs[0], train_inputs[1]], Y_train,
                epochs=100, validation_data=([val_inputs[0], val_inputs[1]], Y_val),
                callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1',
                                           patience=5,
                                           verbose=1,
                                           restore_best_weights=True,
                                           mode='max')])
```

It results with around 0.7 of both F1 and AUC on test set, which I find to be OK as the layers are simple and I didn't use any pretrained word embeddings.

As the next step, I tried to create an LSTM net:

```
# Constructing a LSTM with similar structure
# First head
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[0], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input1)
lstm1 = layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu')(emb1)

# Second head
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[1], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input2)
lstm2 = layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu')(emb2)

# Shared output layers
merged = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([lstm1, lstm2])
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model_lstm = models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

```
model_lstm.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[Precision(), Recall(), f1, AUC()])

model_lstm.fit([train_inputs[0], train_inputs[1]], Y_train,
                epochs=100, validation_data=([val_inputs[0], val_inputs[1]], Y_val),
                callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1',
                                           patience=5,
                                           verbose=1,
                                           restore_best_weights=True,
                                           mode='max')])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/100

2021-10-20 16:48:59.225294: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)

3633/3633 [==============================] - 1605s 441ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - precision: 0.5009 - recall: 0.5091 - f1: 0.3371 - auc: 0.5006 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_precision: 0.5005 - val_recall: 1.0000 - val_f1: 0.6622 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1613s 444ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - precision: 0.4999 - recall: 0.5326 - f1: 0.3529 - auc: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1613s 444ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - precision: 0.5014 - recall: 0.5835 - f1: 0.3863 - auc: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/100
  91/3633 [..............................] - ETA: 25:44 - loss: 0.6933 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - f1: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.4894
etc...
```

The loss freezes at 0.6932 instantly, and AUC doesn't grow over 0.5. Adding more layers and Dropouts didn't help. I find this strange as recurrent nets should outperform Dense ones in NLP.

Both nets were run in Kaggle GPU environment.

Thanks for all possible recommendations!

### Update 21.10.2021

*NB:* Both arrays of my training data (after using Tokenizer(num_words=20000) and padding the sequences) have shape of (116240, 124).

I created a 1D convolutional network which improved test F1/AUC to 0.74/0.77 respectively. The structure is as follows:

```
# Constructing a CNN with similar structure
# First head
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[0], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input1)
conv1 = layers.Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(emb1)
pool1 = layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1)
drop1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(pool1)
flat1 = layers.Flatten()(drop1)
dense1 = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat1)

# Second head
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[1], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input2)
conv2 = layers.Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(emb2)
pool2 = layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv2)
drop2 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(pool2)
flat2 = layers.Flatten()(drop2)
dense2 = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat2)

# Shared output layers
merged = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([dense1, dense2])
dense_out = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_out)
model_conv = models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

```
model_conv.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[Precision(), Recall(), f1, AUC()])

model_conv.fit([train_inputs[0], train_inputs[1]], Y_train,
                epochs=100, validation_data=([val_inputs[0], val_inputs[1]], Y_val),
                callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1',
                                           patience=5,
                                           verbose=1,
                                           restore_best_weights=True,
                                           mode='max')])
```

Also, I built another LSTM model according to @MarcFelix 's tips and tried to tweak the learning rate:

```
# First head
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[0], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input1)
lstm1 = layers.LSTM(256, activation='sigmoid')(emb1)

# Second head
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(sent_vector_len,))
emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_sizes[0], 
                           output_dim=int(sent_vector_len / 4), 
                           input_length=sent_vector_len)(input2)
lstm2 = layers.LSTM(256, activation='sigmoid')(emb2)

# Shared output layers
merged = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([lstm1, lstm2])
dense_out = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_out)
model_lstm = models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

```
model_lstm.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[Precision(), Recall(), f1, AUC()])

model_lstm.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 124)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_6 (InputLayer)            [(None, 124)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_4 (Embedding)         (None, 124, 31)      3323696     input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_5 (Embedding)         (None, 124, 31)      3323696     input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                   (None, 256)          294912      embedding_4[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                   (None, 256)          294912      embedding_5[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 512)          0           lstm_4[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          65664       concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            129         dense_4[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,303,009
Trainable params: 7,303,009
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
model_lstm.fit([train_inputs[0], train_inputs[1]], Y_train,
                epochs=100, validation_data=([val_inputs[0], val_inputs[1]], Y_val),
                callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1',
                                           patience=5,
                                           verbose=1,
                                           restore_best_weights=True,
                                           mode='max')])
```

The result is quite similar to the first one, LSTM still fails to fit:

```
Epoch 1/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1624s 446ms/step - loss: 0.6957 - precision: 0.5000 - recall: 0.5164 - f1: 0.3421 - auc: 0.4992 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_precision: 0.5005 - val_recall: 1.0000 - val_f1: 0.6622 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1620s 446ms/step - loss: 0.6949 - precision: 0.4982 - recall: 0.4964 - f1: 0.3294 - auc: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1641s 452ms/step - loss: 0.6943 - precision: 0.4995 - recall: 0.4903 - f1: 0.3250 - auc: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.6945 - val_precision: 0.5005 - val_recall: 1.0000 - val_f1: 0.6622 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/100
3633/3633 [==============================] - 1646s 453ms/step - loss: 0.6943 - precision: 0.5009 - recall: 0.4871 - f1: 0.3226 - auc: 0.5003 - val_loss: 0.6938 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/100
...
```

Comment: What does your input look like? Is it just a sequence of numbers indicating the indices for the words in the sentence w.r.t. your vocabulary?
It is likely that the reason why your model does not perform is not the actual capability of the model to learn your function, but that there is a reason why it is not able to learn at all. A precision of 0.5 means that your model is basically guessing at random, so it was not able to learn your function in the slightest.

Comment: Additionally, I noticed a substantial flaw in your first model. You use several dense layers, but do not specify an activation function. Multiple chained dense layers without activation function actually perform the same as a single dense layer, so adding an activation function would be a good idea.

Comment: Another idea that I have is that the relu activation function in your LSTM might not be a good idea. With bad initialization, this means that your LSTM's output could blow up to infinity or be almost zero, so an activation function like the sigmoid function is often better for LSTMs.

Comment: The last thing I notice is that it would probably be good to use at least one more dense layer after concatenating the outputs of the two heads. This will give the networks a better chance to actually reason about the connections between the two outputs. This applies to both networks.

Comment: @MarcFelix , thank you for tips! My two arrays of training data both have shape of (116240, 124), where 116240 is the amount of sentences and 124 is the length of padded sentence. Each sentence was cleaned from stopwords, stemmed, passed through Tokenizer(num_words=20000) and padded to length of 124. Should I do anything else to make the input suitable for LSTM?

Adding ReLU's to Dense and shared Dense layer didn't help much themselves, but I trained a 1D-convolutional network with similar structure (respecting to your tips) and got AUC of 0.75. Maybe that could help for future discussion.

Comment: Did you also try the sigmoid activation for the LSTM? And could you maybe update your post with the new/altered models you just described?

Comment: @MarcFelix , done!

Comment: Your models look fine to me. Could you maybe add the output of model.summary() for the LSTM model as well? And can you tell me what the task your models are supposed to do is? And one further note: Usually, one uses the same embedding layer for all input sequences. This is because words typically mean the same, no matter in wich of the two sentences they appear.

Comment: @MarcFelix , summary added. I try to predict whether two sentences belong to the same text or not [(it's a Kaggle dataset)](https://www.kaggle.com/jeffheaton/are-two-sentences-of-the-same-topic). Full version of my current notebook with working models can also be found there.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, so I am running out of ideas for why it still does not work. One diagnostic step you could take is to train the model on a subset of very few sentences (maybe five to 10) and check whether it is able to achieve perfect performance there. If it is not, then there is something fundamentally wrong with the model, and if it is able to learn this subset perfectly then maybe the structure just needs to be improved.

Comment: @MarcFelix , unfortunately such a move didn't give any clues. I reduced my train/test/val to 10/5/5 samples and got test Precision/Recall/AUC of 0.4/1.0/0.5. Validation metrics are even set to zero. My last hope is that my own embeddings are just not enough to represent the texts... But it doesn't explain why Dense and Conv1D fit normally :D But I was going to try the pretrained embeddings anyway. Hopefully the result will be posted in the answer section)

Comment: @MarcFelix , sorry for absence during last days... I tried a couple of additional things like GloVe embeddings and increase of vocabulary size (it was only 20K, though there are ~150K unique words in the dataset)... But LSTM still didn't fit, I managed only to improve my CNN solution to 0.82 of AUC. Thanks for sharing the ideas anyway!